# Реализация strlen() на Си в одну строку

Tags: c, strlen, алгоритм

Давеча побывал на собеседовании, одним из заданий было реализовать функционал `strlen()` без применения сторонних функций, то есть руками. Как полный дилетант в Си я изобразил простой цикл. Мне было указано что данная реализация неэкономна, а также что ее можно записать без лишних переменных и в одну строку. Разумеется не в смысле засовывания все в одну строку, а именно иной алгоритм. Речь не шла о производительности или оптимизации с точки зрения практики, и как я понимаю, вопрос носил чисто академический характер.
Это вызвало у меня интерес, так как на собеседовании я сделать этого не смог. Общаясь с более компетентным коллегой получил от него реализацию:

```
size_t str_len (const char *str)
{
    return (*str) ? str_len(++str) + 1 : 0;
}
```

Я бы пожалуй пока до такого сам не додумался бы, но теперь вопрос у коллеги - существует ли вариант в одну строку без рекурсии?

**PS:**
завел также топик на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520413/c-strlen-implementation-in-one-line-of-code) на одноименную тему.
Надеюсь будет интересно участвовавшим в дискуссии.

Comment: Мне бы тоже такая реализация в голову не пришла.

IMHO тут или рекурсия (порядка strlen(s) лишних переменных, которые просто "спрятаны" в стеке) или "лишняя" переменная.


    size_t strlen (const char *str) {
      register const char *s = str;
      
      while(*str++);
      return str - s - 1;
    }

Немного схитрим и "упрячем" ее в регистр.

Comment: avp, благодарю. Пока это единственное в этом треде что хоть как-то напоминает ответ, но по критерию "в одну строку" все же не подходит.

Comment: @AlexThumb, по крайней мере для gcc могу  и в одну строку написать


    #define STRLEN(s) ({ register typeof((s)[0]) *_start = (s);            \
          register typeof((s)[0]) *_s = _start;                             \
          while (*_s++);                                                    \
          (size_t)(_s - _start - 1); })

только не короче (да и объяснять, почему так, дольше).

Comment: заменять цикл рекурсией это конечно более экономично. а, тут про количество строк речь, мде...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, *формально* (с т.з. компилятора, после препроцессора) это одна строка.

Comment: @avp, да не, я про "экономию", описанную в вопросе. к вашему коду претензий нет. Или вы все-таки про рекурсию?

Comment: Если вопрос не носил практического характера, то по моему этот вопрос не имеет значения. А интересующихся однострочным программированием товарищам, имеет смысл изучить Perl :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Попробую тоже добавить небольшой комментарий к ответу Дож: действительно, если не прибегать к рекурсии, эти самые N итерации должны быть осуществлены с помощью некоего цикла, будь то for, while или do while, откуда возникает принципиальная невозможность сделать алгоритм в одну строку:

если бы даже кому-то удалось написать такой однострочник при помощи любого из этих циклов, в любом случае понадобится как минимум ещё одна строка для того, чтобы вернуть результат:

```
size_t custom_strlen(...) {
    for (крутой однострочник) {}
    return длина; // от этой строки никуда не убежать
}
```

С учётом этого соображения и того, что условие чётко оговаривает лишь "реализовать **функционал strlen()** без применения сторонних функций", я попробовал немного схитрить:

```
void stanislaw_len(char * str, size_t *len) {
    for (*len = 0; *str; ++str, (*len)++);
}
```

**P.S.** Я знаю, что это хак, просто попробовал из спортивного интереса.

---

Более интересно другое: я сравнил предложенные здесь методы и strlen между собой:

```
void stanislaw_len(char * str, size_t *len) {
    for (*len = 0; *str; ++str, (*len)++);
}

size_t KoVadim_len(char * t) {
    return (strchr(t, 0) - t) / sizeof(char);
}

size_t avp_len (const char *str) {
    register const char *s = str;

    while(*str++);
    return (size_t)(str - s - 1);
}

char *STRING = "This is a rather long string! This is a rather long string! This is a rather long string!";

size_t N = 1000000;
size_t M = 10;

__block size_t counter = 0;

Benchmark(M, ^{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        size_t length;

        stanislaw_len(STRING, &length);

        counter += length;
    }
});

NSLog(@"stanislaw_len %ld", counter);

... остальные аналогично
```

Вот результаты для O3:

```
The block have been run 10 times. Average is: 67.163414 milliseconds
2014-03-12 16:59:10.429 SandboxCommandLineApp[17606:303] stanislaw_len() 890000000
The block have been run 10 times. Average is: 72.448875 milliseconds
2014-03-12 16:59:11.156 SandboxCommandLineApp[17606:303] avp_len() 890000000
The block have been run 10 times. Average is: 12.458966 milliseconds
2014-03-12 16:59:11.281 SandboxCommandLineApp[17606:303] KoVadim_len() 890000000
The block have been run 10 times. Average is: 8.514538 milliseconds
2014-03-12 16:59:11.367 SandboxCommandLineApp[17606:303] strlen() 890000000
```

Вопрос к знатокам: **что такого может быть вжато в Apple-овских libc dylib-ах, что такая большая разница есть в скорости? Особенно это непонятно в связи с тем, что последняя опубликованная open source - версия [strlen.c](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-997.1.1/string/FreeBSD/strlen.c) содержит очень схожие посимвольные проходы, как у меня и [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) (вариант KoVadim тут не в счёт, так как он опять же полагается на системную библиотеку) ?**

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, если интересуетесь, посмотрите http://www.strchr.com/optimized_strlen_function и ссылки оттуда.

А [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021066/how-the-glibc-strlen-implementation-works) тоже обсуждают этот вопрос (и есть ссылка на glibc implementation).

Comment: @avp, ещё как интересуюсь! Большое спасибо за ссылку!

Answer (score 14):

В Си невозможно. Всё, что можно записать в одну строку и без вызова других функций, выполняется за время O(1), а нам нужно написать алгоритм, который работает по крайней мере O(N) (N — длина строки).

Answer (score 11):

В формулировке сказано "**без вызова сторонних функций**". А функции **стандартной** библиотеки являются сторонними функциями? Как по мне, то нет. и мой вариант решения тогда такой:

```
int newlen(char * t) {
    return (strchr(t, 0) - t) / sizeof(char);
}
```

По поводу рекурсивного варианта с вопроса - посмотрел скомпилированный вариант (gcc 4.4-4.9 при уровне оптимизации O2, clang 3) - там нет рекурсии - компилятор разворачивает в цикл.

```
str_len(char const*):                          # @str_len(char const*)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpb    $0, (%rdi)
    je  .LBB0_3
    xorl    %eax, %eax
.LBB0_2:                                # %tailrecurse
    cmpb    $0, 1(%rdi,%rax)
    leaq    1(%rax), %rax
    jne .LBB0_2
.LBB0_3:                                # %tailrecurse._crit_edge
    ret
```

Код не идеальный, но достаточно хорош. Никакого стека, никаких лишних обращений к памяти.

Comment: @KoVadim, здорово Вы с рекурсией разобрались!

Почему Вы считаете код gcc 4.4-4.9  не идеальным?

Я посмотрел  

 .ident "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"

для

         Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5400

с -O2 делает основной цикл

     ......
    .L5:
            movl    %edx, %eax
    .L3:
            leal    1(%eax), %edx
            cmpb    $0, -1(%ecx,%edx)
            jne     .L5
    .L2:
            rep
            ret
     ......

    
тут на одну команду больше (а вот про время выполнения ничего сказать не смогу).

Comment: Еще немного поигрался. Самым коротким оказался вариант

    .L9:
            addl    $1, %eax
            cmpb    $0, (%eax)
            jne     .L9
            subl    %edx, %eax
    .L8:
            rep
            ret
    
для текста

    while(*str)
      str++;
    return str - s;

Что интересно, текст

    while(*str++);
    return str - s - 1;

почему-то производит


    .L8:
            movzbl  (%eax), %edx
            addl    $1, %eax
            testb   %dl, %dl
            jne     .L8

другой код внутреннего цикла.

(Загадка...)

Comment: @avp

> Почему Вы считаете код gcc 4.4-4.9 не идеальным?

как минимум, в том коде, который я привел, похоже есть лишний `xorl    %eax, %eax`.

Но не нужно забывать, что современные процессоры очень хитрые. И возможно этот лишний xolr там нужен (Например, он будет спариваться с другой командой и делать более быстрый код в результате).

Comment: Кстати, только что пришло в голову, что если пользоваться другими стандартными функциями (аналогично strchr()), то самым коротким будет

    #define str_len(s) (strcspn(s, ""))

Comment: тогда еще круче будет:

    #define str_len(s) (strlen(s))

Answer (score 0):

```
int strlen(const char* str) {
    for (const char* c = str;;c++) if (!*c) return c-str;
}
```

Comment: Вы понимаете, что отсутствие новых строк не означает, что вы написали код в одну строку?

Comment: В один statement.

Comment: Это, for + if + return, это 3 statement`а, а не 1.

Comment: statement for определяется рекурсивно. Остальные два являются statement, но входят в первый (а третий при этом входит во второй). Если что, можно ссылку на стандарт найти.

Comment: Даже если так, в обычном понимании это не считается за "в одну строку". Иначе какой смысл в этой фразе, если в одну строку можно запихнуть хоть всю программу целиком, минус препроцессорные директивы.

Answer (score -1):

```
int str_len(const char* str) {
    for (char const * a = str, *b = str;;a--,b++) if (!*b) for (int i = 0;; a++, i++) if (a == b) return i / 2;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
int strlen(const char* str) {
    for (const char* c = str;;({ if (*c++ == '\0') return c - str - 1; }));
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Я бы сделал так:

```
size_t SLen(const char *s)
{      
   int k = 0;
   while(s[k++]);
   return --k;
}
```

Comment: Обратите пожалуйства внимание что в теле вопроса я указал что реализовал через цикл, то есть как в Вашем варианте, и указал отдельно что "...разумеется не в смысле засовывания все в одну строку, а именно иной алгоритм"

Comment: таким макаром можно целую операционную систему в одну строку написать. В одну длинную-длинную строку

Comment: Я не собирался все в одну строчку указывать. Просто я выложил с табуляциями и переносами строк, а сайт все сам так сделал...

А так:
size_t SLen(const char *s) { 
return sizeof(s) / sizeof(char) - 1;
}

?

Comment: @Скрыто1, а вот гадать не надо (это я про `sizeof`).

Учите матчасть.

Comment: >Я не собирался все в одну строчку указывать

А какой тогда вообще смысл, если в вопросе явно стоит условие про одну строку? К тому же ТС изначально сказал, что вариант с циклом был опробован

Comment: В смысле гадать? 


Или чем это решение:

size_t SLen(const char *s) { return sizeof(s) / sizeof(char) - 1; }

не устраивает?

Comment: @Скрыто1, вы пробовали вот это "size_t SLen(const char *s) { return sizeof(s) / sizeof(char) - 1; }" запускать?

Comment: Нет, но догадаться, что бы преобразовать тип в int - думаю не сложно.

size_t SLen(const char *s) { return (size_t)(sizeof(s) / sizeof(char) - 1); }

Если вы про это?

Comment: @Скрыто1, не зря Вас минусуют.

--

У Вас `sizeof(s)` - это размер указателя, а `sizeof(char)` (как ни странно) это 1. Тут дело в том, что в Си (и С++) размер, который дает `sizeof()` это размер объекта не в байтах, а в `sizeof(char)`.

Для получения размера в битах `sizeof()` надо умножать на константу `CHAR_BIT`, определенную в `<limits.h>`.

Ну, а для пересчета в байты надо знать, сколько бит в Вашем байте (не везде в байте 8 бит).

Comment: char str[] = "0123456789";
cout << sizeof(str) / sizeof(char) - 1;

Так - работает.

> это размер объекта не в байтах, а в sizeof(char).

Ну вот, если sizeof(char) вернут нам количество байт, которые выделяет компилятор для символа (например turbo C++ и ms vc++), а sizeof(str) - сколько байт выделено для массива. То почему sizeof(str) / sizeof(char) - 1, не должно возвращать правильную длину массива?

Я сам только новичек, может я и не прав.

Comment: И чем отличается код, который вы добавили, от моего варианта:

size_t SLen(const char *s) { int k = 0; while(s[k++]); return --k; }

?

Почему у меня не правильно, а у Вас все  - правильно?

Comment: @Скрыто1, понятно, что новичок.

Вы путаете указатель (в ответе)

    SLen(const char *s) 

с массивом (в комментарии)

    char str[] = "0123456789"

Синтаксис выражений (в правой части, конечно) будет одинаковым, а вот суть все-таки немного разная. 

Массив будет занимать 11 байт в памяти (проинициализирован строкой "0123456789" (с учетом нуля в конце)), а параметр `s` это 4 байта  в стеке (для 32-бит CPU) (или 8 в регистре (тех же, традиционных, 8-мибитных для 64-бит CPU).

Вы все-таки книжки какие-нибудь повнимательней почитайте. K&R для начала.

--

А код с циклом *ни чем не отличается*.

Comment: `size_t` требует дополнительной строки `#include`

int slen(const char *s) {const char *s1; for(s1 = s; *s1; s1++); return s1 - s;}

Comment: @alexlz, с вашего позволения модифицирую

int slen(const char *s) {for(const char *p = s; ; p++) if (!*p) return p - s;}

считаем, что 1 строка = 1 оператор

Comment: @paulgri А что, в Си уже есть 

    for(const char * p = s; ; p++)

А "одна строка -- один оператор" -- так вспоминается "круглая программа", оформленная в виде круга из символов. С активным использованием макросов. Может кто вспомнит, а то гугл её не знает.

Comment: >вспоминается "круглая программа"

да [вот][1] например

[1]:http://habrahabr.ru/post/132665/

Comment: @alexlz, виноват, не обратил внимание, что речь только о C, а не C/C++. Так бывает только в C99 и плюсах, но хотелось и возврат, и декларацию спрятать внутрь одной конструкции ))